# Draggable in Vue 3 won't display value

Tags: vue.js, draggable, vuejs3, sortablejs

I am using `Vue draggable` to sort items from my `Store.js` by drag and drop (I've simplified my example here using only  `['a', 'b', 'c']` as my store data).

I am also using a computed property made accessible from the `setup()`

```
    <draggable v-model="myList" item-key="id" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" >
        <template #item="{card}">
            <p>{{ card }}</p>
        </template>
    </draggable>
```

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    components: {
        draggable
    },
    setup() {
        const cards = computed(() => {
            return ['a', 'b', 'c']
        })
        return {
            cards
        }
    }
}
```

I know the template iterates through `cards` but no value is displayed or is neither accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 3 - When `setup` is executed, the component instance has not been created yet. As a result, you will not have access to `data`, `computed`, `methods` component options.

Reference:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-component-properties

Also in Draggable component, the array item will be accessed by `element` variable.

Updated template code:

```
 <draggable v-model="myList" item-key="id" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" >
            <template #item="{element}">
                  <p>{{ element.value }}</p>
            </template>
    </draggable>
```

Try changing the component code as follows,

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    components: {
        draggable
    },
    data:function(){
     return {
       drag:false
     }

    },
    computed:{
      myList:function(){
          return [{id:1,value:'Card A'},{id:2, value:'Card B'}];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: with no access to any value in the template, this returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Just found the exact issue, the array item can be accessed via the dedicated 'element' variable. Now it should works @Philx94

Answer (score 2):

yarn add vue-draggable-next

```
  <draggable class="w-full mt-5 dragArea list-group" :list="list" @change="log">
    <div
      class="max-w-md p-2 mb-5 border cursor-pointer list-styles"
      v-for="element in list"
      :key="element.name"
    >
      {{ element.name }}
    </div>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { VueDraggableNext } from "vue-draggable-next";
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    draggable: VueDraggableNext,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      list: [
        { name: "Medical science", id: 1 },
        { name: "Allied Medicine", id: 2 },
        { name: "Defense Service", id: 3 },
        { name: "Education training", id: 4 },
        { name: "Economics & Commerce", id: 5 },
        { name: "Banking & Finance", id: 6 },
        { name: "Enginnering", id: 7 },
        { name: "science", id: 8 },
      ],
      dragging: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    log(event) {
      console.log(event);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```